# shell script running inside devcontainer Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: shell-script

the below test.sh running in windows command prompt working as expected. however when running inside devcontainer it got failed

```
files=(
    "first" 
    "second"
    )

for i in "${files[@]}"
do    
    echo $i 
done
```

Error running in devcontainer

**test.sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected**

[image]

Please guide me how to resolve this error

Comment: Run it with some shell that supports arrays, e.g. Bash or ksh, not with a standard POSIX shell

Answer (score 6):

You are running that using `sh` which is not `bash` and does not support arrays. Use `bash` instead of `sh` and it should work fine. Alternatively, add a shebang line to the beginning of your script:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

Then, make it executable (`chmod a+x script.sh`) and you can just run it with `/path/to/script.sh`.

To illustrate the problem:

```
$ sh -c 'list=("a" "b"); echo "OK"'
dash: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
$ bash -c 'list=("a" "b"); echo "OK"'
OK
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes it is working , i was using in gitbash terminal in windows, however executing with bash test.sh working fine. thanks a lot